# Magento2: Calling upsell block from phtml is not working.

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, custom-block

I want get up-sell product block. when I am working with XML script block is working. but when I am trying to this in .phtml file it's showing nothing .I do not what is wrong with .phtml and XML data is working good .

step1: For xml  this code working good

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell" name="product.info.upsell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" after="product.info.media.video">
    <arguments>
       <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">upsell</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Step:2 for .phtml file this code is showing blank

```
 <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell')->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: use $this instead of $block,

Comment: @ Prasanta Hatui @ No luck it's not working, I do not why it's happen , code is good becouse if i call other template instead of itmes.phtml  it's working

Answer (score 0):

use above code in phtml file:-

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell")->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: what is new in this code

Comment: Jagriti Joshi@No luck it's not working

Answer (score 0):

We can not call upsell block this way from phtml file. Because upsell products are associated with a product.

It will working fine when calling from xml because it retuns upsell products for current product.

If you want to get upsell products from current product then you can try below code:

```
<?php 

  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $currentProduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product

      if ($currentProduct) {

        $upSellProducts = $currentProduct->getUpSellProducts();

        if (!empty($upSellProducts)) {
            echo '<h3>UpSell Products</h3>';
            foreach ($upSellProducts as $upSellProduct) {
                $productId = $upSellProduct->getId();
                $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId); 
                echo $product->getName().'<br />';
                echo $product->getSku().'<br />';
                echo $product->getProductUrl().'<br />';
                echo $product->getImage().'<br />';        
            }
        }

     }
?>
```

Comment: Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined property: Magento\ProductVideo\Block\Product\View\Gallery\Interceptor::$frameworkViewLayout in /opt/lampp/htdocs/daydaybag/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php on line 110

Comment: this error showing after used this

Comment: let me check the error

Comment: @@Prasanta Hatui @you there?

Comment: @@Prasanta Hatui @you answer is  older . I have used this but this code only return data , does not result default product data

Comment: I have given this code because you can get from here. However if want to get like default , you have to put html here.

Comment: echo $product->getImage(). only show the url  image , how can i put the html format

Comment: like this <img src"<?php echo  $product->getImage() ?>" />

Comment: Prasanta Hatui @ thanks for response , I think i have to deign layout page

Answer (score 0):

From the thread at [Notice: Undefined variable: exist in Magento 2 when using upsell block](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178280/notice-undefined-variable-exist-in-magento-2-when-using-upsell-block)

```
echo $this->getLayout()
->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell')
->setData('type', 'upsell')
->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml')
->toHtml();
```

So the key is `->setData('type', 'upsell')`